# Javascript: Parse JSON with extra curly braces

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have this JSON object:

```
var dataObj = { data: '\n{ sizeMap:{\nxSizes: "REGULAR|SMALL", \ncurrItemId: "",\ncurrItemSize: "",\nmanufacturerName:"Rapid",\npartNumber: "726G", \nsuitStyle: "R",\nhasSC: "",\nhasInseam:""\n}\n}',type: 'text',next: null,prev: null };
```

I'm trying to read the `sizeMap` object inside the `dataObj.data` value with:

```
 console.log(dataObj.data.sizeMap);
```

But it's `undefined`. I tried `JSON.parse(dataObj.data)` which errors with:

```
{ sizeMap:{
  ^
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token s
```

The output of `console.log(dataObj.data)` is:

```
{ sizeMap:{
  xSizes: "REGULAR|SMALL",
  currItemId: "",
  currItemSize: "",
  manufacturerName:"Rapid",
  partNumber: "726G",
  suitStyle: "R",
  hasSC: "",
  hasInseam:""
  }
}
```

So there are extra braces wrapping the JSON? Note: this is in Node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not JSON, that's a JavaScript object. JSON is a text format for representing data.

The string `data` inside the object isn't JSON either. To be valid JSON it would need quotation marks around all the property names:

```
{
  "sizeMap": {
    "xSizes": "REGULAR|SMALL",
    "currItemId": "",
    "currItemSize": "",
    "manufacturerName":"Rapid",
    "partNumber": "726G",
    "suitStyle": "R",
    "hasSC": "",
    "hasInseam":""
  }
}
```

Note that the brackets should actually be there, that's not the problem.

The string would work as a JavaScript, so you could use `eval` to turn it into an object:

```
eval("(" + dataObj.data + ")").sizeMap
```

Naturally the usual precausion applies whenever you use `eval`. As it executes the code, you have to be sure that noone can put anything harmful in the string.

Comment: When I run `eval(dataObj.data).sizeMap` I get this error `currItemId: "", SyntaxError: Unexpected token : `

Comment: Ok fixed the error by running: `eval("(" + dataObj.data + ")")`

Comment: @jrbaldwinn: Right, it's interpreted as a code block instead of an object literal.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not valid. Try running it through a tool like http://jsonlint.com/

The keys need to be wrapped in quotes too.

For example

```
{
    "sizeMap": {
        "xSizes": "REGULAR|SMALL",
        "currItemId": "",
        "currItemSize": "",
        "manufacturerName": "Rapid",
        "partNumber": "726G",
        "suitStyle": "R",
        "haSC": "",
        "hasInseam": ""
    }
}
```